# Navigate between screens use react-navigation

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to use ***react-navigation*** to navigate between the pages of the app, but I got into trouble in a particular case!

I have three pages I want to move around.
First of all, on page 1, which is my home page, I want to go to page 2

After page 2 I want to go to page 3
So everything goes right.
Now I want to go from page 3 to page 2 with load new information.

But what happens is that the last step is actually like the back button, and I can not reload the page 2 and display the new information.

I followed the document and use `this.props.navigation.push ('Details')}`

how can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function from screen 2 to screen 3 and call that function on back press and in the implementation of that function at screen 2 you just call whatever you want to do for reload.

You can check [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/887#issuecomment-299714800) answer for help.

Comment: thanks, but I want to click the item of the list in screen 3 and go to screen 2 with new data and must reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this functionality by using `DeviceEventEmitter`

**Page2.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';
export default class page2 extends React.Component {
listeners = {
        update: DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('page2Back', (object) => {
            //code for reload page
        })
    }
    ....
    ....

}
```

**Page3.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';


  export default class page3 extends React.Component {
   //back button tap action
   onBackPress() {
        DeviceEventEmitter.emit('page2Back', {})
        this.props.navigation.goBack()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to click the item of the list in screen 3 and go to screen 2 with new data and must reload the page.

Comment: @miladsolgi you can passing new data into emit method, currently i pass blank object, you can pass your new data instead of blank object.

Comment: My main problem is not passing data. it really reloads the page. when I go to screen 2 its resume from the last position of the page. or another problem is effect close screen 3 like back button effect.

Answer (score 0):

you can use callBack for to achieve that:

```
export default class Page2 extends Component {
   onReloadPage(){
    //do what you want to update information
   }
  gotoPage3(){
     this.props.navigation.navigate('page3',callBack:this.onReloadPage.bind(this)
     }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      ...
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And in Page3 screen, you have to call this method which works like a back event listener

```
export default class Page3 extends Component {

  onGoBack(){
     this.props.navigation.state.params.callBack(); //you can also pass param in this method
      this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
     }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      ...
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `page 2` when you come back from `page 3` **get the data you passed from page 3** in `_componentFocused` the syntax i have shown below.

For the reload to occur **you must have saved the older data in some state and when you navigate back from `page 3` a state change must occur with passed data**.

A `compoentDidFocus` is a new life cycle will get added soon but can be triggered with the below syntax.It will get called every time when we move into a `component`.

**And also make the state change in `compoentDidFocus` inside an if condition. in that if condition check whether you are coming from  `page 3` to `page 2` not first time entering into `page 2`.**

```
componentDidMount() {

      //paste the below code in componentDidMount

            this._componentFocused();
            this._sub = this.props.navigation.addListener(
                'didFocus',
                this._componentFocused
            );
        }


      //paste the below code above render same place we call `componentDidMount`

   _componentFocused = () => {
           if(// check if you are coming from page 3){
               // make the state change with page 3 data
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Let's break this down:

this.props.navigation: the navigation prop is passed in to every screen component (definition) in stack navigator (more about this later in "The navigation prop in depth").
navigate('Details'): we call the navigate function (on the navigation prop — naming is hard!) with the name of the route that we'd like to move the user to.
If we call this.props.navigation.navigate with a route name that we haven't defined on a stack navigator, nothing will happen. Said another way, we can only navigate to routes that have been defined on our stack navigator — we cannot navigate to an arbitrary component.